# Capture sub-directories from path

Tags: regex, perl

```
my $path= "/tmp/main/store/important/file/log"; ##string

$path =~ m/file/;

print "$&/$'\n";
```

I want to capture `file/log/.*/.*/ .. . . ..`

And the path may vary, any other way to solve this?

Thanks guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use greedy matching (`.*`):

```
my $path= "/tmp/main/store/important/file/log";
my ($tail) = $path =~ m!(/file/.*)!;
print $tail;  # /file/log
```

Here I also use a custom delimiter for the `m//` operator to avoid escaping slashes.